# Multiple ajax calls with different vars in success

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

> **UPDATE:** Problem was in other place. I made 3 calls with same attribute. So if you have same issue **check attribute value before $.ajax**

I have **jQuery ajax call**:

```
function foo(someVar){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'http://some.json?callback=?',
        success: function(data){
            alert(someVar);
        }
    });
}
```

If make **multiple call**:

```
getPriceByRoute('a');
getPriceByRoute('b');
getPriceByRoute('c');
```

will get 3 alerts with `c`.

**How can I send my `someVar` to succes function?**

Tried to do:

```
function foo(someVar){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        //
        myVars:{someVar:someVar},
        //
        url: 'http://some.json?callback=?',
        success: function(data){
            alert(this.myVars.someVar);
        }
    });
}
```

but same result.

In last case I can send every next request after previous load, but hope there are other good solution.

Comment: norepro: http://jsfiddle.net/YkkGv/

Comment: @Juhana, sorry we have some virus on server and some sites don't work. jsfiddle is one of them :)

Comment: The point being, if I call `foo('a'); foo('b'); foo('c');` I get a, b, and c alerted (in varying order) as they should. Are you sure this is the code you have?

Comment: yes, probably it returns response straight, try to add other json server, for example `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=narekmarkosyan&count=4&calback=?`

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. The variable is local, other calls to the same function can't change it.

Comment: You're within scope, so as Juhana has pointed out, you have access to `someVar` inside the success function, just not as `this`.

Comment: @Juhana ahh you are right. I make `foo('c');foo('c');foo('c');`... problemin `$.each` what make calls to function. Flu disabled my brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `context` option in `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    context: {someVar:someVar}, // sets the value of "this" inside the success function
    ...
    success: function(data){

        // "this" is {someVar:someVar}, as set via the context option
        alert(this.someVar);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. After adding `context` I lost my vars from `data:{}` part. Is there problem with using both?

Comment: No. `context` has nothing to do with `data`. `data` is what your server returns, `context` has nothing to do with it. Must be some other issue.

Comment: Yes, I undo last changes and add you code and it works. but problem was in other place. Thanks.